# Powerpoint macro to format table (position, size, font, alignment)

Tags: vba, formatting, powerpoint

I have a PowerPoint with about 10 slides, each slide has one table that needs to be formatted the same way.  I am using the below macro to format the text within the tables, but I dont know how to combine this code with other formatting such as row height and table position.

Please can someone help me by adding to the below code the following preferences:

- Table horizontal position = 1cm from left
- Table vertical position = 3cm from top
- Table width = 23.5cm
- Table sent to back
- All row heights as small as posible
- All Text middle aligned (vertically)

  ```
  Sub format()

  Dim s As Slide
  Dim oSh As Shape
  Dim oTbl As Table
  Dim lRow As Long
  Dim lCol As Long

  For Each s In ActivePresentation.Slides
      For Each oSh In s.Shapes
          If oSh.HasTable Then
              Set oTbl = oSh.Table
              For lRow = 1 To oTbl.Rows.Count
                  For lCol = 1 To oTbl.Columns.Count
                      With oTbl.Cell(lRow, lCol).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange
                          .Font.Name = "Calibri"
                          .Font.Size = 7
                      End With
                  Next
              Next
          End If
      Next    ' Shape
  Next s
  End Sub
  ```

Answer (score 1):

I have played around a bit more, and I've answered my own question:

```
Sub format()

Dim s As Slide
Dim oSh As Shape
Dim oTbl As Table
Dim lRow As Long
Dim lCol As Long

For Each s In ActivePresentation.Slides
    For Each oSh In s.Shapes
        If oSh.HasTable Then
            oSh.Left = 1 * 28.3
            oSh.Top = 3 * 28.3
            oSh.Width = 23.5 * 28.35
            oSh.ZOrder msoSendToBack
            Set oTbl = oSh.Table
            For lRow = 1 To oTbl.Rows.Count
               For lCol = 1 To oTbl.Columns.Count
                With oTbl.Cell(lRow, lCol).Shape
                    .TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Name = "Calibri"
                    .TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size = 7
                    .TextFrame2.VerticalAnchor = msoAnchorMiddle
                    oTbl.Rows(lRow).Height = 0.5
                    End With
                Next lCol
            Next lRow
        End If
    Next oSh    
Next s

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I see you figured it out (good job!). One other useful thing relating to your need "All row heights as small as possible" is to just do this:

```
oSh.Height = 0
```

...sometimes a couple of times depending on the table's content.